# Cannot test WCF service in Visual Studio. "There was no endpoint listening."

Tags: visual-studio, wcf, web-services

I am attempting to test a WCF web service I'm developing by accessing it using a Winforms client in Visual Studio. The WCF service is being hosted by the Visual Studio ASP.NET development server, and I can see it when I access it via my web browser (it gives me the "You've created a service." page). However, when I attempt to connect to it through the Winforms client (which is configured to point to my local service), it says:

> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost:8181/{Web Application}/{SVC File}.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

There is no value in InnerException. `{Web Application}` and `{SVC File}` are actually populated with the correct values, I just removed them from the exception message.

**Any ideas as to why this isn't working and how I can correct it?**

Comment: Is it just this service, and can you get other WCF client/server connections going? Maybe make a simple solution (from scratch) with the default WCF template and a simple client. Worst, case, disable the firewall and start VS as Admin.

Comment: @Henk: At this point I'm trying to get it working in local IIS, but I'm encountering the same issue (it's trying to load 4.0 assemblies even though it targets 3.5) as I was on the testing server. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417257/inexplicable-assembly-load-in-wcf-service-iis-7). If I can get that working, then I won't much care about VS not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to use local IIS rather than the ASP.NET development server, which is a good habit.  Once you do this, make sure you have anonymous granted with permission for the new Web application.

Second, add the web service as a Service Reference.

Third, I used this snippet to test a web service under the above circumstances:

```
Private Sub cmdSearch_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSearch.Click
    Dim ws As New ServiceReferenceName.WebMethodsSoapClient()
    Dim bs As New BindingSource()
    bs.DataSource = ws.NAmeofMethodinWebService(txtSearchCriteria.Text)
    DataGrid1.DataSource = bs
    DataGrid1.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually working on doing this (I haven't yet been able to get this service working on an IIS server, including my local box).